# what are pointwise Optimizers and non-pointwise Optimizers?

Tags: machine-learning

I recently read the doc about fairscale FSDP
[EFFICIENT MEMORY MANAGEMENT](https://fairscale.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deep_dive/oss_sdp_fsdp.html)

Where it mentioned

4. Results should be identical to DDP with pointwise Optimizers, e.g., Adam, AdamW, Adadelta, Adamax, SGD, etc.. However, the sharding will result in slightly different results when using non-pointwise Optimizers, e.g., Adagrad, Adafactor, LAMB, etc.

I do understand how adam and adagrad working but I not not fully understand what cause the difference between pointwise Optimizers and non-pointwise Optimizers?

Comment: As mentioned in the machine-learning tag, questions about ML theory are off-topic on Stack Overflow but may be on-topic on other sites. You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info)